# Do Kshatriyas exist in Kaliyuga

Tags: puranas, kali-yuga, varna, kshatriya

Many brahmins held this belief that no Kshatriyas exist in kaliyuga .Can someone refer me to scriptural injunctions on whether Kshatriyas exist in Kaliyuga or not ?

Comment: "Many brahmins held this belief that no Kshatriyas exist in kaliyuga" - Which Brahmins? there are many sub types and categories in Brahmins. You need to explain your question further for clarity. This is unheard.

Comment: Nāgeśsabhatta produced his Vrātyatāprāyaścittanirnaya at a śāastrasabhā in Jaipur, where he argued that there were no pure Ksatriyas surviving in the Kali age, and that the impure ones do not have the eligibility for Upanayana through some expiation. So the Kāyasthas could not claim to be genuine Ksatriyas either. It was this opinion of Nāgesabhatta, counter to the opinion of Gāgābhatta, that steadily gained popularity among the Pune Brahmins during the rule of the Peshwas, finally reflected in the activities of Nīlakantha Thatte.

Comment: This was the reason Shivaji for his coronation brought in Gagabhatta,because brahmins in Maharashtra refused to do his vedic coronation

Comment: The son of Mahánanda will be born of a woman of the Śúdra or servile class; his name will be Nanda, called Mahápadma, for he will be exceedingly avaricious 18. Like another Paraśuráma, he will be the annihilator of the Kshatriya race; for after him the kings of the earth will be Śúdras. He will bring the whole earth under one umbrella:

Comment: This is from Vishnu Purana

Comment: See my mahananda comment..It is quoted from Vishnu Purana only  see quote 18             https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp117.htm

Comment: War of Mahabharat was about ending all top races of Kshatriyas. Hence, now only mediocre Kshatriyas are there out of karma. So the quality has certainly degraded, hence adharma has increased. Typical of kalyug. (IMO, not scriptural)

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.** 

If you want scriptural injunctions for Kali Yuga, the easiest place to look would be Parashara Smriti:

> [image] 
> 1.24 For the Krita are suited the laws of Manu ; for the Treta, those
> by Gautama (are) prescribed ; for the Dvapara those by Shank and
> Likhita ; **for the Kali, those by Parashara are prescribed**.

As for Kshatriya varna, there are 15 places as far as I can see where it is mentioned. That means the Kshatriya varna does exist in Kali Yuga. 

Example:

> [image] 
> 11.12 **A Kshatriya**, or a Vaishya leading a religious life,
> and duly engaged in the ceremonies prescribed for his
> caste, — should on all occasions partake of food in his house,
> whenever a ceremony for the gods or for departed ancestors
> takes place in his house.

So, Kshatriyas do exist in Kali Yuga.

Comment: And what about vishnu Purana ? Which says no Kshatriyas exist after Nanda annihilated them .?

Comment: @bhatnagarprakhar I can't provide a scriptural reason for the difference between both scripture verses, but it could be that Nanda annihilated most Kshatriyas while the wives did niyogas with Brahmin rishis similar to when Parashurama annihilated most Kshatriyas or that some escaped. See [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46221/if-parshuram-killed-kshatriyas-21-times-how-do-many-kshatriyas-like-rajputs-exis) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12438/leftover-kshatriyas-after-lord-parashuramas-genocide).