# How can Narasimha & Vamana Avatars happen before Parashuram?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, parashurama, vamana

Following is the chronological order of these three avatars:
Narasimha avathar (4th of vishnu )
Vamana avathar(5th of vishnu)
Parasuram avathar(6th of vishnu)

Accordingly:

- In Vamana avathar king Mahabali defeated by vishnu's 5th avathar
- In Narasimha avathar Hiranyakasipu was defeated by 4th avathar of Vishnu

Now the family tree of kashyapa was:: 
Kashyapa--> Hiranyakasipu--> Prahalada--> Vairochana--> Mahabali

Parashuram avathar had gifted the land to kashyapa after defeating kshyatrias as a honor of conducting ashwamedhas. Here the Parashuram avathar was the 6th of Lord Vishnu.

How can this be possible in terms of chronology?

Check details in these links in order:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parashurama //this shows about Parashuram donating land to Kashyapa
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahabali //this shows the tree structure of Kashyapa's family &&"Compare the links of kashyapa in LINK "1 and 2 refers to same"

Comment: Why can't Parashurama donate land to Kashyapa? How is it connected to Narasimha and Vamana?

Comment: The resolution is simple: Kashyapa is a Chiranjeevi, so he was alive before the time of Hiranyakashipu and he was still alive at the time of Parashurama.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiranjivi  @keshav he is not a chiranjivi it's clearly mentioned in the link

Comment: @surya read my question again I was mentioned the all information in my description

Comment: @NaveenGopalNollu Those seven are not the only Chiranjeevis, as that link makes clear: "While there are others as well, which are not included in the one particular shloka."  Kashyapa is also a Chiranjeevi, because he's one of the Saptarishis.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan why don't you make answer out of it.

Comment: @keshavSrinivasan can figure out such document or any links regarding kashyapa is immortal please

Comment: @keshav Srinivasan I don't want to make answer I need it with proof

Comment: @NaveenGopalNollu OK, I posted an answer with proof.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resolution is simple: Kashyapa is a Chiranjeevi, so he was alive before the time of Narasimha, and he continued to be alive in the time of Parashurama.

[Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=M_lKAQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA869&ots=LRNyrvIW7h&dq=%22eternal%20kashyapa%22&pg=PA869#v=onepage&q&f=false) is what the Harivamsa says:

> In the course of time **the eternal Kashyapa** begat all created beings on Daksha's daughters.

And [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b119.htm) of the Anushasana Parva of the Mahabharata shows that Kashyapa has lived for at least 30,000 celestial years:

> Once on a time, O king, a ruler of the name of Anga desired to give away the whole earth as sacrificial present unto the Brahmanas. At this, the earth became filled with anxiety. 'I am the daughter of Brahman. I hold all creatures. Having obtained me, alas, why does this foremost of kings wish to give me away unto the Brahmanas? Abandoning my character as the soil, I shall now repair to the presence of my sire. Let this king with all his kingdom meet with destruction? Arrived at this conclusion, she departed for the region of Brahman The Rishi Kasyapa, beholding goddess Earth on the point of departing, himself immediately entered the visible embodiment of the goddess, casting off his own body, by the aid of Yoga. The earth thus penetrated by the spirit of Kasyapa, grew in prosperity and became full of all kinds of vegetable produce. Indeed, O king for the time that Kasyapa pervaded the earth, Righteousness became foremost everywhere and all fears ceased. In this way, O king, the earth remained penetrated by the spirit of Kasyapa for thirty thousand celestial years, fully alive to all those functions which it used to discharge while it was penetrated by the spirit of Brahman's daughter. Upon the expiry of this period, the goddess returned from the region of Brahman and arrived here bowed unto Kasyapa and from that time became the daughter of that Rishi, Kasyapa is a Brahmana. Even this was the feat, O king, that a Brahmana did. Tell me the name of the Kshatriya who can be held to be superior to Kasyapa!

As you can see in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5253/36), one celestial year is 360 human years, so at the very least Kashyapa has lived for 10.8 million years!

And by the way, it's not like Kashyapa was involved with Varaha and Narasimha, was absent during the Vamana Avatara, and then suddenly reappeared during the time of Parashurama.  On the contrary, Vamana himself was the son of Kashyapa and Aditi as described in [this chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/17) of the Srimad Bhagavatam.

And Kashyapa was even involved in the Mahabharata! He's mentioned as one the sages that Yudishthira will meet in his Tirtha Yatra in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03085.htm) of the Vana Parva of the Mahabharata:

> Those foremost of Rishis, Valmiki, and Kasyapa, and Atreya, and Kundajathara, and Viswamitra, and Gautama, and Asita, and Devala, and Markandeya, and Galava, and Bharadwaja, and Vasishtha, and the Muni Uddalaka, and Saunaka with his son, and Vyasa, that best of ascetics, and Durvasas, that foremost of Munis, and Javali of great austerities--all these illustrious Rishis endued with wealth of asceticism, are staying in expectation of thee. With these, O mighty king, do thou meet by visiting these tirthas.

This makes clear the longevity of Kashyapa.

Comment: @UdayKrishna Ys, I discuss this in my question and answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/433/36

Comment: @UdayKrishna Parashurama annihilated the kings of the Earth 21 times, not 14.