# Whose skull is in Siva’s necklace that Virabhadra mentioned to Narsimha?

Tags: shiva, puranas

Virabhadra while trying to subdue Narasimha mentions about some form of Vishnu leaving his skull in Siva’s necklace during Kurma avatar. Which story Virabhadra is referencing about?

[image]

This is mentioned in verse 49-50 of Chapter 11 of [Satarudra Samhita](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12959/3/Chapter1_1070-1148p.pdf) of Shiva Purana. (Sorry I could not find direct link to chapter 11)

Comment: I don’t understand the downvote. Do I need to rephrase the question or add something? Pls comment

Comment: Verse says it is burnt skull of Kurma. Shiva wears skulls of all Devas. See [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9590/3500).

Comment: You will **always** get downvotes for such questions.. You have to spend a lil bit of more time on this site and you'll realise what I've to say..:D @Ketan

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thank you. I went through Srimad Bhagvatam, Vishnu Purana and Mahabharata section of Ocean churning stories but I couldn’t find anywhere how and why Siva wore Kurma’s head . Do you know where else I should look at? your post above answers in generic way about skulls of devas. I was just curious if there is any story that I am not aware of :-)

Comment: @Ketan Yes. I will search and let you know. And probably this will be mentioned in Shaiva Puranas.

Comment: @Ketan Your question only has an image that too not clear. Image only questions and answers are considered low quality but people tend to vote on it based on their emotions. You should add the information in text. That is the reason for downvote. Ignore the comments which say nothing is wrong in the question. There is wrong. Also, no need to post comments about why you are downvoted. You receive some random downvotes on site. It is natural.