# Why Marichi is called Maruts?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, rishi

This is what Krishna says in the Bhagavad Gita:

> Of the Ādityas I am Viṣṇu, of lights I am the radiant sun, of the
>   Maruts I am Marīci, and among the stars I am the moon.

Let's focus on    `of the Maruts I am Marīci` part.

[Marichi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marichi) is the son of Brahma, as [discussed](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3704/why-was-surya-killed-by-lord-shiva) in this post. Below is the mention of Marichi, in that discussion.

> Kashyapa is the son of Marichi, one of the mind-born sons of Brahma

Now as per the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maruts), the the Marutas (Sanskrit: मरुत), also known as the Marutagana and sometimes identified with Rudras, are storm deities and sons of Rudra and Prisni.

**My Question is**: Why Marichi is called Marutas(sons of Rudra and Prisni) when Marichi is considered as the son of Brahma?

Is there any scripture reference which describe Marichi as Maruts (apart from Bhagavad Gita shloka which is mentioned above).

Or did I get it completely wrong and that Marīci(mentioned in Bhagavad Gita) and Sage Marichi are 2 totally different people?

Comment: [Chapter 8 of Matysa Purana](http://www.indianscriptures.com/Content/Articles/PDFs/23204/25F_Chapter_8.pdf) says Indra is lord of Maruts.

Comment: Madhvas comment....
It should be noted that His vibhuti or divine, transcendental opulence of Marici is not referring to one of the ancient sages of antiquity. His vibhuti of Marici is the primal breath that sweeps across all space preceding the Maruts which are the different types of powerful winds throughout the unlimited trillions of universes.

Answer (score 2):

Swami Paramarthananda in his [lectures on Bhagawad Gita based on Sankaracharya Bhashya](http://arshaavinash.in/index.php/download/bhagavad-gita-swami-paramarthananda/) explains Marichi as follows

> a set of dēvathās are called marut ganaḥ; 49 in number; sapta sapta;
> seven groups of maruts; in each group seven members are there; and
> they are supposed to preside over the vāyu tatvam. So there are
> different types of vāyu dēvathās; presiding over the wind. So among
> these 49 marut dēvathās; I am Marichihi; Marichi is the dēvathā; who
> presides over that beautiful breeze which will make us feel very
> pleasant; Marichi means that tender beautiful breeze; not the cyclonic
> storm; that cool breeze which you get in [Courtalam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtallam) and all that
> places; that cool, gentle pleasant air-conditioning breeze is presided
> over by marichi dēvathā; Therefore Krishna says I am the Marichihi;
> among the marut ganāḥ.

The "sapta sapta" can also be validated from [Aditya Hridayam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adityahridayam) as

> haridaśvaḥ sahasrārciḥ **saptasaptirmarīcimān**
>
> timironmathanaḥ śambhustvaṣṭā mārtāṇḍa aṃśumān

So it is **not Sage Marichi** that is referred here.

Hope this helps you.