# Hindu Belief on Conception

Tags: superstitions, birth

I thought according to Hinduism, it is proper for woman to conceive at night. If she conceives at daytime, the children are weak and short-lived. I read it on a website that has explicit paintings, hence I didn't provide the link.

However, I am watching Shiv Mahapuran and this episode mentions how demons and gods belong to same father, Sage Kashyap. However, the mother of the demons, Diti desires to conceive at night so that her children can become strong like demons.

Here is the YouTUBE link, starting at that scene (26 minutes and 10 seconds)

[Diti, Mother of Demons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8zMexFpXk0&feature=youtu.be&t=26m10s)

Please clarify, what is the Hindu belief on best time a woman should conceive for healthy, honest, children.

Comment: It isn't night... It is Sandhyakaal (or just after sun set)... it may be inauspicious for conception at that time... but I think these cases are like Kaaktaliya Samyog... ie.. a crow sits on a brach of bilva tree and then bilva fruit falls from that branch.... crow thinks that fruit fall due to his sitting... other who saw also tell fruit fall due to sitting of crow... but the fruit had fallen naturally.. it was just coincidental circumstance.. although sitting of crow and falling of fruit aren't related they seem to be related.. similarly conception time and baby may just seem to be related..

Comment: @Tezz Thank you for clarifying. I guess if it was night (hours after sunset) then conception is ok.

Comment: @Tezz I think above example you mentioned is unrelated here. Those events are independent. I think this has scriptural reference. i don't remember exactly what scripture. See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6938/3500) which is same as what OP mentioned in her question.

Comment: @Rhonda yes, it's ok in night... the video you have mentioned also tells... "Diti it's dusk time" in 25:45 and at 26:00 it says "It's sunset"....

Comment: @Tezz Ah, now I understand

Comment: @The Destroyer Kaaktaliya samyog is standard example given in Advaita... as per Advaita even as the answer says it's due to that... they are still unrelated... they just seem to be related... it's a bit hard concept... birth of good baby and bad baby depends on Karma of parents and child itself... so, time do not have any role.. but karma of good and bad baby circumstances create good and bad time for their conception (unmanifested state)... so that there is coincidental circumstance... events just seem to be related... events itself create circumstancial coincidence...

Comment: @Rhonda [Chapter 13 of this book](https://archive.org/details/VeerabrahmendraThePrecursorOfKalki1) says proper time to conceive though it doesn't mention time in a day. i think this has scriptural reference may be manusmriti or a Purana which i don't remember now. Will check and tell you.

Comment: @TheDestroyer This is quite interesting.

Comment: @Tezz i understand that you are talking from absolute perspective. Even Yoga Vasishta mentions the above crow example innumerable number of times. But i think this MAYA , though confusing, follows some rules and we can understand with logic till certain level. I think we can systematically get out of MAYA in contrary to what people believe.

Comment: @The Destroyer yes, it's all Maya... if we tell whether good child or bad child gets birth depends on time of conception... then it becomes contrary to law of Karma... but the Karma itself do not make it contradiction... in unmanifested state it itself creates such circumstances that it becomes connected to auspicious and inauspicious time... but still they are unrelated... but they are related... related.. unrelated... related.... unrelated... It's all Maya... hehe..

Comment: @Tezz I think we are discussing Advaita here.  All this is verily MAYA and even Karma, conceiving, good and bad. Only Consciousness (Brahman) is true but people conceive in such as that it is accordance with previous Karma. If anyone studied this and avoided that, it could be due to some good karma. We say such statements of crow examples to just say the nature of MAYA. But Karma  (Law of Cosmos) must be **fair** and **fair** doesn't look meaningful if we can't understand with our mind. Let us discuss this further in our chat room.

Comment: The proper way for conception to occur as a religious rite is given in the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad VI. iv. 1-28. Have a Brahmin explain it to you and your husband.